# Recovering in Amazon Cognito MFA

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I have implemented TOTP [MFA with AWS Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa.html) with boto3 python. Everything is working fine, But I would like to know how to reset MFA in case a device is lost.
I did not find any mechanism in the documentation. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old question, but I'd like to leave an answer in case anyone else shows up.

TL;DR: Cognito does not have this feature, you need to workaround it, and only if you use MFA as optional. If MFA is set to required on the user pool, you will need an admin to reset the user.

See:

- https://medium.com/@akash.verma926/how-to-recover-amazon-cognito-users-who-has-lost-their-totp-devices-8f3472c5c5d5
- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4828
- [AWS Cognito - reset user MFA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497388/aws-cognito-reset-user-mfa)