# Amazon Cognito MFA on a user by user basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, two-factor-authentication

Based on the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497388/aws-cognito-reset-user-mfa) and [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-set-user-mfa-preference.html) it seems like we can enable/disable MFA (TOTP or SMS) on a user by user basis.  Just want to confirm that this is the case for both the client API (AWS Amplify) and command line?

Also can we select MFA SMS or TOTP on a user by user basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent or aws:MultiFactorAuthAge conditions in an IAM policy on various APIs.

MFA can be set per user too.  You shouldn't use SMS 2FA though if it can be avoided.

Comment: I have set MFA as optional. While signUp some users not received code and there MFA is still disabled.How can i enable this MFA for this type of users?

Comment: Go into your IAM panel and toggle it

Comment: What shall I need to toggle. Can you give any steps. Also can I able to trigger this in the UI code while calling Auth.signUp

Comment: @sejn ran into the same issue, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @YashKalwani I didn't get any solution.