# Respond to MFA_Setup challenge - React, Node/express, AWS-sdk app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have react app at front-end and node/express at back-end.

For all Congito users, MFA is mandatory.

The flow for normal login in my application is (without MFA) is as below,

1. Cognito user enters Username & Password (in React custom login page), credential goes to node/express API, using `AWS-sdk` version `2.X.X` and `initiateAuth` method, user will be able to get tokens. And, tokens are sent back to FE and user goes to Dashbaord.

With MFA enabled,

1. Cognito user enters Username & Password, credential goes to node/express, using `initiateAuth`, it tries to login but user gets

   ```
   {
     "ChallengeName": "MFA_SETUP",
     "Session": "AYABeG0B9dZro_HAB...",
     "ChallengeParameters": {
        "MFAS_CAN_SETUP": "[\"SMS_MFA\",\"SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA\"]",
        "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "user1"
     }
   }
   ```

Now, I don't know what should I do? There are many videos and articles I have gone through but the flow is not clear.

Somewhere (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKuX_YNykPQ) I saw, next step is to generate `QR code` and then scan the QR code but for that we need `AccessToken`. As you can see in above code snippet, I don't get `AcessToken`.

I really have no idea which is next step and proceed further.

Comment: I would recommend going though this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761546/1273882

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Seems pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

> You're getting **MFA_SETUP** as next challenge because MFA is not configured for the user.

Once you receive this kind of response, you need to configure MFA for the user by showing a QR Code so that the user can use the Authenticator app to scan the code and get 6 digit code.

### How to setup MFA to get 6 digit OTP

> This answer make use of AWS CLI, you can use respective method in SDK.

1. First, make a call to `associate-software-token` to get secret key code.

   ```
   aws cognito-idp  associate-software-token --session "Session ID from InitiateAuth"
   ```

   The response looks like below.

   ```json
   {
      "SecretCode": "string",
      "Session": "string"
   }
   ```
2. Second, use the `SecretCode` to setup MFA device, and get 6 digit code.

   - Use [libqrencode](https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode/) to generate a QR code, and scan that code from Authenticator app.
   - Add this secret key code in you Authenticator app manually, or use https://totp.app/ for temporary purpose.
3. Once you get 6 digit OTP, you need to call `verify-software-token` to mark software token MFA status as **verified**.

   ```
   aws cognito-idp verify-software-token \
   --user-code "123456" \
   --session "Session ID from AssociateSoftawareToken"
   ```

Once this is done, and MFA is configured, next you are given another challenge `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA`.

### Get the Cognito Tokens by completing SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA challenge

Respond to this challenge as shown below.

1. Case A: When you first time configure MFA

   ```
   aws cognito-idp respond-to-auth-challenge \
   --client-id <CLIENT_ID> \
   --challenge-name MFA_SETUP \
   --challenge-responses USERNAME=<USERNAME> \
   --session "Session ID from VerifySoftwareToken"
   ```
2. Case B: When MFA is already configured

   ```
   aws cognito-idp respond-to-auth-challenge \
   --client-id <CLIENT_ID> \
   --challenge-name SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA \
   --challenge-responses USERNAME=<USERNAME>,SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA_CODE=123456 \
   --session "Session ID from InitiateAuth"
   ```

This returns you a response like this.

```
{
    "ChallengeParameters": {},
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "eyJraWQiOiJhV05MR0xZbmJYdmhM.....",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "TokenType": "Bearer",
        "RefreshToken": "eyJjdHkiOiJKV1QiLCJl....",
        "IdToken": "eyJraWQiOiI5OFhVN1oyQzRzQ3BQZE...."
    }
}
```